# Is there a way to only require one echo in this scenario?

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

I have the following line of code:

```
for h in "${Hosts[@]}" ; do echo "$MyLog" | grep -m 1 -B 3 -A 1 $h >> /LogOutput ; done
```

My hosts variable is a large array of hosts

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't require me to echo on each loop? Like grep on a variable instead?

Comment: You do not have to echo, replace `echo "$MyLog" | grep -m 1 -B 3 -A 1 $h` with `grep -m 1 -B 3 -A 1 $h <<< "$MyLog"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That has the side effect (I believe) of using a temporary file, rather than an in-memory pipe buffer.

Comment: Do you want to keep the same order in LogOutput?  If not, it seems like you just want to use a better pattern to match multiple strings.  Either way, seems like one pass with awk is what you want.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Wiktor, I thought I had tried this one already and disregarded it 
due to being extremely intensive and long to complete. But I just tried it again and it was almost instant so I must have been tried something else instead.

Comment: Do `-m 1` and `-A` work well together? In BSD `grep`, at least, `grep` stops reading input after the first match is found, so no trailing context is output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Order does matter for my case, the output file is a list of times of when an item has been backed up. So it needs to be most recent first.

Comment: Why is the log in a variable to begin with?

Comment: The stored file is quite large so I'd rather have it only temporarily available.

Answer (score 0):

No `echo`, no loop

```
#!/bin/bash
hosts=(host1 host2 host3)
MyLog="
asf host
sdflkj
sadkjf
sdlkjds
lkasf
sfal
asf host2
sdflkj
sadkjf
"
re="${hosts[@]}"
egrep -m 1 -B 3 -A 1 ${re// /|} <<< "$MyLog"
```

Variant with one `echo`

```
echo "$MyLog" | egrep -m 1 -B 3 -A 1 ${re// /|}
```

Usage

```
$ ./test
sdlkjds
lkasf
sfal
asf host2
sdflkj
```

Comment: How would this work when outputting the egrep to a file? I've tried egrep -m 1 -B 3 -A 1 ${re// /|} <<< "$MyLog" > /LogOutput  but this didn't work, only the first egrep item gets logged

Comment: Looks like i didn't understand your idea, `-m 1` need to be removed or loop added.

Answer (score 0):

One `echo`, no loops, and all grepping done in parallel, with **GNU Parallel**:

```
echo "$MyLog"  | parallel -k --tee --pipe 'grep -m 1 -B 3 -A 1 {}' ::: "${hosts[@]}"
```

The `-k` keeps the output in order.
The `--tee` and the `--pipe` ensure that the `stdin` is duplicated to all processes.
The processes that are run in parallel are enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

printf your string to multiple-line that you can then grep? Something like:

```
printf '%s\n' "${Hosts[@]}" | grep  -m 1 -B 3 -A 1 $h >> /LogOutput
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on GNU system. otherwise `info grep`

From `grep --help`

```
grep --help | head -n1
```

Output

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
```

So according to that you can do.

```
for h in "${Hosts[@]}" ; do grep -m 1 -B 3 -A 1 "$h" "$MyLog" >> /LogOutput ; done
```